# Insert field with formula (hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, formula

I need to set one of fields from another select before insert object.

I create property like:

```
        <property name="measureIndex" not-null="false" type="integer">
            <formula>(SELECT MAX(measure.measureIndex)+1 from measure WHERE measure.schemaId = schemaId)</formula>
            <column name="measureIndex" default="1" />
        </property>
```

But error has thrown - nested exception is: `org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: com.dataswell.core.domain.api.Measure.measureIndex type: integer`

Comment: try to remove <column name="measureIndex" default="1" />, as you have a Formula you cannot have also a column to read data from.

Comment: you right, but now if select get no any measureIndex - result is null, and I need 1 as default

Comment: which rdbms do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try :

```
<property name="measureIndex" not-null="false" type="integer">
  <formula>(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(measure.measureIndex),0)+1 from measure WHERE measure.schemaId = schemaId)</formula>
</property>
```